# Importing numpy gives ImportError: cannot import name TestCase

Tags: python, numpy, import

I'm working on a remote desktop server, Windows XP Profesional. About 2 hours ago numpy was still working on there. I was trying to paralelise a for loop using `mulitprocessing.Pool()` and I must have done something wrong, because after a short time there were 100ish python.exe processes running. It took me some time to get back in on the server, and I wanted to test why all those processes got made. However, I ran into the following error:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>

    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in <module
>
    from type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in <modu
le>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 45, in <modu
le>
    from numpy.testing import Tester
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\__init__.py", line 8, in <mo
dule>
    from unittest import TestCase
ImportError: cannot import name TestCase
```

I can import unittest.py, but I can't import TestCase:

```
>>> import unittest
>>> from unittest import TestCase
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name TestCase
```

I have the same problem running python from Eclipse as running it from the command line. However, when using different Python (also 2.7, but 32-bits) it does work.

I first tried reinstalling numpy, but this did not solve the problem. The only other solution I found is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10917375/651779) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917245/numpy-importerror-cannot-import-name-testcase). However, I've looked and deleted all unittest.py files, and I still have the same problem. I don't know what to try next.

Comment: Specifically, in `Python27\Lib\unittest\__init__.py`, line 47 should say `__all__` = [<long list; should contain `TestCase`>], and TestCase should be defined in case.py

Comment: Does `unittest.__file__` point to where it should? If it does, and points to `.pyc` file, try deleting the `pyc` first

Comment: @NiekdeKlein I'm not sure if you'll have to reinstall everything, unfortunately.

Comment: @CodyPiersall In Python27\Lib\unittest\__init__.py `__all__` contains TestCase

Comment: @Zhenya deleting the `__init__.pyc` file it pointed to, restarting python and doing `import unittest`, `from unittest import TestCase` fixed the problem, thanks! Do you know how this could have happened? And can you write your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: I deleted my first comment (suggesting to reinstall Python) because I don't want anyone to do that without reading @Zhenya's comment.  I'm also very interested in why deleting the .pyc file worked.

Comment: @CodyPiersall I'd love to have an answer to the 'why' question as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(moving it from comments)

Apparently, `.pyc` files can get stale. Quoting
http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201310/finding_stale_pyc_files.html:

> Recently I was debugging one of those "it can't happen" kinds of
>   problems, and wanted to make sure I didn't have any stale .pyc files
>   lying around.

So, the first thing to try is to check what exactly is being imported: `print(unittest.__file__)`. You've checked that it's not a stray `unittest.py` in the working directory. OK. If it's a `.pyc` file, just try deleting it. No harm possible, it'll get regenerated next time you're importing it.

I've to admit I've no intelligent answer to the 'why' question. If anybody more knowledgeable than I can answer it, I'd happily upvote and delete this answer.

Comment: +1 for solving the OP's problem and making me aware that .pyc files can be problematic.  I'm still interested in the why; hopefully someone will enlighten us.

Comment: @CodyPiersall credit should really go to Ned --- all I know about it is from his post.

Comment: If someone has the same problem, after deleting the .pyc file, if you are still in the python shell you first have to quit() and start python again, before import unittest. I get the problem when I accidentally made a fork bomb while multiprocessing an application where I use numpy, where due to some mistake (don't know which) I produce hundreds of python instances, which I have to kill off. Maybe the .pyc didn't finish being created fully due to the process being killed mid import?

Comment: @NiekdeKlein While restarting the interpreter works, it might just be enough to `reload(unittest); from unittest import TestCase`.